# Pandas groupby and transform takes long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Given a `DataFrame` similar to this (but with over a million rows and about 140000 different `group`s)

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'group': {1:'A', 2:'A', 3:'A', 4:'A', 5:'B', 6:'B'},
                        'time' : {1:1,   2:3,   3:5,   4:23,  5: 7,  6: 12}})
```

for each `group` I want to find the difference between the `time` (which is actually a `dtype('<M8[ns]')` in my real df) and the minimum time for that `group`.

I have managed it using `groupby` and `transform` as follows:

```
df_test['time_since'] = df_test.groupby('group')['time'].transform(lambda d: d - d.min())
```

which correctly produces:

```
    group   time    time_since
1   A       1       0
2   A       3       2
3   A       5       4
4   A       23      22
5   B       7       0
6   B       12      5
```

but it takes almost a minute to compute. Is there a faster / smarter way to do this?

Comment: Doing any python calculations is going to inherently make your code slow, as those functions have to be called on every single row of your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion:  doing `lambda`(calculation) outside the `transform`, so we do not need lambda here. With the `lambda` , we calling the calculation couple times (Depends on how many groups)

```
df_test=pd.concat([df_test]*1000)
%timeit df_test['time']-df_test.groupby('group')['time'].transform(min)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
%timeit df_test.groupby('group')['time'].transform(lambda d: d - d.min())
The slowest run took 7.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: are you using the python builtin min? If so, I think this could be sped up with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html but I am not familiar enough with pandas to really know

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Went from 150s to 0.5s. Thanks!